# Ubuntu 16.04 unstable, freezes/booting problems

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, freeze

short story: Where can I find which video card driver to use?

Long story:

new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation freezes when I press ¨restart now¨ at the end of the installation. After reboot: kept sending me back to the screen where my password was asked whenever I entered my password (correctly). I tried all kings of ¨fixes¨ run from recovery mode: none of which worked. -> Reinstalled Ubuntu (again erased whole disk etc). Again restart now / booting and shutdown freezes (but loggin went fine?! using same USB stick) So I changed grub line to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.

I updated the whole system and changed the Graphic driver to the newest nvidia, everything seemed to be fine! Next day I try to boot: after the Bios boot the Ubuntu boot only showed a black screen with in the left top corner a: ¨-¨. So installed Ubuntu again.. same Grub fix, But because the only things I changed yesterday was the video driver I think that is where my problem lies and hence: Where can I find which driver is best for my:

- hp g3 zbook
- Quadro M1000M Nvidia card
- I7 6400 Quadro

Ubuntu even froze when I tried to type this message, 16.04 LTS looks very unstable to me, anyone else having similar problems? Any clue on maybe a hidden problem in my kernels? Thanks in advance for all the help

Kind regards Steven

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us is where nvidia keeps drivers. Ensure you know what you need. Is this the one you've tried?
http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/126577/en-us
This link is for version 384.98 for M1000M, which is specified for Linux.
Nice gear. Good luck.

Comment: Use that page to check for compatible driver versions. DO NOT DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL FROM THERE! Install the correct version from the Ubuntu repositories instead (easily done at Additional Drivers, BTW). A couple of reasons for this: 1. Nvidia drivers provided by Ubuntu have been patched and tested to work in the specific Ubuntu release and 2. Drivers provided by the Nvidia binary have to be reinstalled whenever the kernel is updated (this is in all likelihood the OP's problem) .

Comment: [nVidia driver reset after each kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492217/nvidia-driver-reset-after-each-kernel-update)

Comment: Thanks guys! I did install the 384.98 via the additional drivers menu last time.. I will check the side for compatibility and try it again! 

This morning again had troubles booting.. try 1: upon booting the boxes blasted in a high pitched sound and froze when I tried to reboot.. try 2: froze again on login page. try 3 I booted via the Bios and everything seems normal again now.. (no recovery mode, just via the bios and "Continue boot")

Comment: So I Installed the 384 driver via the assitional driver menu, which nvidia says is compatible with my hardware. But my whole system crashed within 10s of me pressing the apply button.. After rebooting I got stuck in on the login, not even recovery mode enabled me to.login.. So reinstalled ubuntu...any ideas? 384 is clearly not compatible..

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')`

AND after that

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs:i386`

and let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

In the BIOS change graphics to 'discrete'